# Using ParquetFileWriter to write data into parquet file?

Tags: parquet

I am newBee to parquet!
I have tried  below Example code to write data into parquet file using **parquetWriter** .

http://php.sabscape.com/blog/?p=623

The above example uses parquetWriter, But I want to use ParquetFileWriter to write data efficiently in parquet files.

Please suggest an example or how we can write parquet files using **ParquetFileWriter** ?

Comment: what's the difference between `ParquetWriter` and `ParquetFileWriter`

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get some idea from a parquet column reader that i wrote [here](https://gist.github.com/tispratik/f0044dd84dc8d8c6cbcf).